# Join multiple rows of on table into array for joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, express

I have a table called `idcards` with a foreign key on the id of the table `reservations`. Then I have a table `photos` that has a foreign key on the id in table `idcards`.

I want to select all from idcards where the reservation id is a certain value, plus the photos that are attached to this idcard.

This is what I have so far, but it obviously selects only one photo per idcard:

```
SELECT i.*, p.photo 
FROM idcards AS i 
INNER JOIN photos AS p 
    ON (i.id=p.iId) 
WHERE i.resId = 1
```

How can I make it so the idcards that I get have an array with all the photos ?

Comment: What does "array" have to do with your question?  MySQL doesn't support arrays.

Comment: 'obviously selects only one photo per idcard:' - not obvious to me , I would have said this results in 1 row per photo..Please add sample data and expected outcome as text to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon youre right, it does, thank you :)

Comment: I suspect you are looking for group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the field `photo` from the table `photos`, you can group them in an array, associating it to the idcard, with a query like the following:

`SELECT i.*, JSON_ARRAYAGG(p.photo) FROM idcards AS i LEFT JOIN photos AS p ON (i.id=p.iId) WHERE i.resId = 1 GROUP BY i.id;`

Or the following, to return the photos in a same field, separed by a comma:

`SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(p.photo) FROM idcards AS i LEFT JOIN photos AS p ON (i.id=p.iId) WHERE i.resId = 1 GROUP BY i.id;`